# Heroku / Postgres Error: integer out of range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, migration, heroku

I am getting `PGError: ERROR: integer out of range` message from trying to insert the following integer: 100001389928198.

According to the [Postgres docs on numeric datatypes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) the limit is much higher (9223372036854775807). I have a feeling Heroku is treating the column as a regular integer rather than a BIGINT.

I defined the migration as a BIGINT as such:

```
t.column :uid, :bigint
```

is this not correct in terms of Heroku migrations?

Comment: wow that's a big number! What are you using it for?

Comment: its a facebook uid (for oauth stuff)

Comment: I see. So I guess we will start using these larger int fields now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure `t.column` is same as `change_column` or not, but here is how according to api

```
change_column :table_name, :uid, :bigint
```

Comment: my original migration was as stated above, but running this one did the trick. thanks!

Comment: this worked for me too.. surprising given that :bigint isn't listed as one of the column types in the migrations guide and that :limit => 8 seemed to work for me on pg locally..

Comment: Hmm...I tried this and got the error undefined method `bigint' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x000000045beb50> Ended up doing   t.integer :field, :limit => 8 instead to limit the size.